# References in initializer list

Tags: c++

I have a camera class with two reference variables. I want to pass in two references through the constructor and assign the reference variables to these, so that if I change these in this class, the other ones I defined before (and passed in) will change too. However, I get the error:

```
a reference of type "D3DXMATRIX &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "D3DMATRIX"
```

and

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'D3DMATRIX' to 'D3DXMATRIX &'
```

here is my code:

header:

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>   
#include "globals.h"
#include "direct3D.h"

class Camera
{
private:
D3DXMATRIX &matProjection, &matView;
public:
Camera(
    float fOVDeg, float nearCull, float farCull,
    float xPos, float yPos, float zPos,
    D3DMATRIX &matProjection, D3DMATRIX &matView);
void SetCamera(float fOVDeg, float nearCull, float farCull);
void AdjustCamera(float x, float y, float z);
};

#endif
```

source:

```
#include "Camera.h"

Camera::Camera(
float fOVDeg, float nearCull, float farCull,
float xPos, float yPos, float zPos,
D3DMATRIX &matProjection, D3DMATRIX &matView) 
: matProjection(matProjection), matView(matView)
{
this->SetCamera(fOVDeg, nearCull, farCull);
this->AdjustCamera(xPos, yPos, zPos);
}

// Set the fixed properties of the 3D camera
void Camera::SetCamera(float fOVDeg, float nearCull, float farCull)
{
// create a projection matrix
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
    &matProjection,
    (float)D3DXToRadian(fOVDeg),    // the horizontal field of view
    (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
    nearCull,    // the near view-plane
    farCull);    // the far view-plane
}

// Set the adjustable properties of the 3D camera
void Camera::AdjustCamera(float x, float y, float z)
{
D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (x, y, z),
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                   &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
}
```

Obviously I am misunderstanding something fundamental. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The errors I get are on the initialiser list in the constructor.

here is where I am instantiating the camera:

```
Camera* camera;
D3DMATRIX matProjection, matView;

//called once
void Initialise(HWND hWnd)
{
initD3D(hWnd);
    init_pipeline();
cube = new Cube();

level = new Level(*cube);

camera = new Camera(
    45.0f, 1.0f, 10000.0f,
    0.0f, 9.0f, 100.0f,
    matProjection, matView);

test = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: The compiler tells you which line the error occurs on.

Comment: Show the relevant code where you instantiate a `Camera` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you are trying to initialize reference to Derived with a reference to Base, as in:

```
class D3DMATRIX {};
class D3DXMATRIX : public D3DMATRIX {};

class Camera {
private:
    D3DXMATRIX& m_;

public:
    Camera(D3DMATRIX& m) : m_(m) {}
};
```

MSVC9.0 says:

```
test.cpp(9) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'D3DMATRIX' to 'D3DXMATRIX &'
```

Maybe you should have Camera constructor taking D3DXMATRIX& as parameters?

Comment: [`D3DMATRIX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172573(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`D3DXMATRIX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172912(v=vs.85).aspx) seem to be unrelated from a quick google check.

Comment: [DirectX reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says they are...

Comment: Ooops... I just read the original definition in the top part (probably the C version). There seems to be some discrepancies on the definitions of the data types in C and C++ in D3D... I am glad I don't need to fight those :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is D3DXMATRIX derives from D3DMATRIX.  You can't store a reference to a D3DMATRIX as a D3DXMATRIX.

So, either pass in D3DXMATRIX in the first place, or store D3DMATRIX instead.  Here's a trivial example that also doesn't work:

```
class A
{

};

class B : public A
{

};

class C
{
public:

    C(A& a) : MyB(a) {}

private:

    B& MyB;
};
```

Comment: It seems that the two types are not related by inheritance, from the docs: [`D3DMATRIX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172573(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`D3DXMATRIX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172912(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Look at the code, not the docs: typedef struct D3DXMATRIX : public D3DMATRIX

Comment: Sorry, there seems to be two different definitions for C and C++... (ouch)

Comment: I expect so.  Typical Microsoft obfuscation!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us where you instantiate `Camera`, or any line numbers.

But you're probably trying to bind a temporary to those non-`const` reference parameters in your constructor.

Why not store a `const D3DXMATRIX&`, or else make a copy.